# Why "-3 >> 1" does not produce the same result as "-3 / 2"?

Tags: c++, operators, difference, integer-division

Consider the following c++ code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int a = -3 >> 1;
    int b = -3 / 2;

    cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When executed, this code give this result:

```
a = -2, b = -1
```

I'm a little puzzled, because I thought that these 2 operations produced the same code in the compiled exe, i.e. something like:

```
shr ax, 1
```

But it seems that it's not the case (I tested with 2 different compilers). Somebody can explain to me why these operations doesn't produce the same result?

**---- EDIT ON the 17.02.2018 ----**

Well, I know this is a newbie question, even if I'm not really a beginner in C++

In fact, I understand perfectly what happen in binary when I apply a shift right (i.e. shr or >> operator) on a value. **This was not my question**.

Rather, my question was about the **difference** between **applying a binary shift on a value** or **make a division on a value**. **I expected that the result was the same**, because until now I assumed that the compiler replaced a division by 2, or a multiplication by 2, by the appropriate shr/shl instruction during the compilation, as an optimization. Assuming that, the produced binary should be the same for the both instructions, so **the result should also be the same**.

But it is **apparently not the case**. For that reason, I would be happy to know what happen under the hood while the compiler **compiles** these both instruction (analyzing a mnemonic is not really my strong point), what are their differences, and finally, this should let me understand why the result differs in mathematical terms.

As a concrete case, I faced this issue in a source code for a graphical application I tried to make simpler. To facilitate the human reading of the code, I replaced some code like "(widthB - widthA) >> 1" by "(widthB - widthA) / 2". But doing that introduced a bug: several graphic items were no longer centered as expected. From that I noticed that replacing the shifting by a division produced different result if the value to divide was negative, it's the reason of the above question.

I hope this will clear up the situation.

Comment: First of all, dispel from your brain the notion that C++ is defined in terms of CPU operations

Comment: It's not clear to me which part is puzzling you. Do you not see why `-3 >> 1` produces `-2`, or why `-3 / 2` produces `-1`?

Comment: Regarding your edit, there's one very fundamental aspect you've missed, I think: it's not that they produce different results because they get compiled differently. That's backwards. They get compiled differently because they're *supposed to* produce different results (in part because the standard says so, in part because it's dependent on the implementation and the implementation says so). `-3 >> 1` is supposed to produce `-2`, and `-3 / 2` is supposed to produce `-1`, and if they're supposed to produce different results, they clearly require different instructions.

Comment: thx hvd, your comment answered my question. That was exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4):

-3 in two's complement system

```
11111111111111111111111111111101       :BIN
```

And when shift right

```
11111111111111111111111111111110       :BIN
```

That's mean -2 in decimal.

But when you divide two number like `-3 / 2` the answer is -1.5 and when cast it to integer it be -1.

Comment: How about a one's complement system?  Since C++ supports both.  For sake of completeness.

Comment: @Eljay that's different
~3 -> 11111111111111111111111111111100 
and shif right
11111111111111111111111111111110 -> ~1

it's different -3 and ~3 
-3 is  two's complement 
~3 is  one's complement

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way signed and unsigned numbers are represented internally, if you give this code a shot you will see that it behaves as expected.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        unsigned int a = 3 >> 1;
        unsigned int b = 3 / 2;

        cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

I suggest looking up "twos compliment"

Comment: C++ does not require two's compliment.

Comment: @user4581301 yet I am not aware of any modern platform which is not using 2's compliment.

Comment: @SergeyA that's only because Jack Tripper messed up Three's Compliment with his wacky antics.